# Triangle data structure not working for LoD algorithm

Tags: java, lwjgl, data-structure, vbo, level-of-detail

I would like to implement a LoD algorithm to my 3D game in order to simplify meshes at certain distances from the player. My meshes are created / loaded using a VBO, so the vertex data is stored in a very large float array as

```
float[] vertices = {x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3 ... xn, yn, zn};
```

How would I use this data in something like `edge colapse`? Would I need to convert this data into a more usable data structure such as a list of faces, or would it be possible to use this directly?

I feel like it would be very difficult to use the vertex array directly, so I have a simple class to represent a triangle using a `Vector3f` for each vertex, and an `Edge` class for each edge. The data structure for these are pretty simple, I dont feel that I need to show the whole code, so just a simple overview:

The `Triangle` class stores

- 3 `Vector3f`s to represent each vertex
- 3 `Edge`s to represent each edge
- an equals and hashcode implementation to be able to compare

And the `Edge` class stores

- 2 `Vector3f`s to represent each vertex
- a float representing the length of the edge: `abs(magnitude(subtract(v1, v2)))`
- an equals and hashCode implementation to be comparable

I have a method to convert the vertex array into a list of triangles, but it isn't working properly.

```
public static List<Triangle> vertexArrayToTriangles(float[] vertices, int[] indices)
{
    List<Triangle> result = new ArrayList();
    Vector3f[] vertexList = new Vector3f[vertices.length / 3];

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length / 3; i++)
    {
        vertexList[indices[i]] = new Vector3f(vertices[i], vertices[i + 1], vertices[i + 2]);
    }

    int i = 0;

    while (i < vertexList.length / 3)
    {
        result.add(new Triangle(vertexList[indices[++i]], vertexList[indices[++i]], vertexList[indices[++i]], new Vector3f(0, 1, 0)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

This just makes a spiky jumbled mess of triangles that is extremely laggy to render. Also, during rendering, the triangles are converted back into a float array of vertices.

How would I convert the vertex array into a `List<Triangle>` and keep the indices in order?

Comment: Edit: Oh, thats java... nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length / 3; i++)
{
    vertexList[indices[i]] = new Vector3f(vertices[i], vertices[i + 1], vertices[i + 2]);
}
```

In your first run, you're taking `vertices[0]`, `vertices[1]` and `vertices[2]`, in your second run you're taking `vertices[1]`, `vertices[2]` and `vertices[3]`, see where the problem is?

And i don't get why you're using `vertexList[indices[i]]`, this makes no sense.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i+=3)
{
    vertexList[i/3] = new Vector3f(vertices[i], vertices[i + 1], vertices[i + 2]);
}
```

---

```
int i = 0;

while (i < vertexList.length / 3)
{
    result.add(new Triangle(vertexList[indices[++i]], vertexList[indices[++i]], vertexList[indices[++i]], new Vector3f(0, 1, 0)));
}
```

Here you're iterating from 0 to vertexList.length, but you can have more indicies than vertices.

```
for(int i = 0; i < indices; i+=3)
{
    result.add(new Triangle(vertexList[indices[i]], vertexList[indices[i+1]], vertexList[indices[i+2]], new Vector3f(0, 1, 0)));
}
```

If the indices start counting from 1, like the `wavefront .obj`-format does it, you have to subtract 1 from every index.

---

If this still doesn't work, try passing `{ 1, 2, 3, 4}` as vertices and `{0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3}` as indices and step through it with the debugger.